# Android Parcelable duplicate object

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

Let say I have 2 class ChildModel and ParentModel

```
public class ParentModel implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private String value;
    private ArrayList<ChildModel> childs;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %d %s", "[PARENT]", id, value);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public ArrayList<ChildModel> getChilds() {
        return childs;
    }

    public void setChilds(ArrayList<ChildModel> childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }


    public ParentModel() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.value);
    }

    protected ParentModel(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.value = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<ParentModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ParentModel>() {
        public ParentModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ParentModel(source);
        }

        public ParentModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ParentModel[size];
        }
    };
}
```

and

```
public class ChildModel implements Parcelable {
    private int id;
    private String value;
    private ParentModel parent;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public ParentModel getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(ParentModel parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s %d %s", "[CHILD]", id, value);
    }

    public ChildModel() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.value);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.parent, 0);
    }

    protected ChildModel(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.value = in.readString();
        this.parent = in.readParcelable(ParentModel.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<ChildModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ChildModel>() {
        public ChildModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ChildModel(source);
        }

        public ChildModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ChildModel[size];
        }
    };
}
```

When passing `ArrayList` of 2 `ChildModel` into the second activity, although in Activity 1, these 2 `ChildModel` have the same `ParentModel`, but here these 2 have 2 different `ParentModel` (the same value for each field in the `ParentModel`). So anyone know how to fix this ?

To be more general, is there any mechanic that allow when write the same object into parcel twice, it would only point to the same memory in the `Parcel` ?